# Close counter gone

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The question [How is "per se" used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121995/when-you-use-per-se) had a close vote: "Other - asker does not know what per se means"; I added my vote to it.

Asker changed the question, but the vote counter is gone. I cannot vote to close since I get "You already voted to close."

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reopened the question shortly after you voted to close it. I will add further explanation here in a few minutes, but there's another Meta post that I'm in the midst of writing that I want to address first.

---

Further explanation: On this question, 3 close votes were for "unclear what you're asking" and the other 2 were for custom off-topic, with the comment being

> The OP does not seem to have understood the expression 'per se' in the first place."

I thought (1) it was abundntly clear what the OP was asking, i.e. whether or not those sentence used *per se* correctly, and (2) while the custom comment is *factual*, it is invalid as a close reason. The OP is essentially trying to ask if he/she is using the phrase correctly, which is inherently based on whether or not he/she understood the phrase in the first place.

Furthermore, it appeared that users may have voted to close the question because it was initially two questions. In that case, the appropriate close reason would have been "too broad".

In any case, I did not feel an argument was to be made for closing the question under any close reason.

Comment: But I still COULD not close it as a GR since I already voted to close it before - and the counter was not visible, but now I see my counter

Comment: @mplungjan You can only vote to close a question once. The counter you are seeing is someone else's vote, who has just voted to close that question; it is not your close vote

Comment: I do not understand why my vote is not showing. Hence by original question. Is it by design?

Comment: @mplungjan The counters only reflect current active close votes. When the question was closed, your vote was used.

Comment: So no matter if the question has been completely altered, if I voted to close it before I may never vote to close it again?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes. You may, however, flag for moderator attention if you feel the question should be closed nonetheless.

Comment: No need for flagging, I had just never seen this. I feel if the question had been closed and reopened and edited, a person with enough rep should be allowed to vote to close it again if his vote had been removed..

Comment: @mplungjan That would take to "close questions" wars, if users were allowed to vote to close a question every time it is re-opened. The only users who can vote to close a question more than once are moderators.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed some of us were adult